# Error 1054 al ejecutar sentencia sql al final del ciclo

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Tengo una tabla MySQL que se llama `empleados`, estoy en la opción `modificar`, este es el código final del ciclo `modificar`:

```
sql="update Empleados set numdocEmp='"+numdocEmp+"', NombreEmp= '"+nombreEmp+"', salariobasico= '"+salbasicEmp+"', \ Fechaingreso= '"+fechaingEmp+"', NombreEPS= '"+nombre_eps+"', NombreAFP= '"+nombre_afp+"' where IdEmpleado="+idEmpleados

cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Se aceptan todos los cambios pero al final se muestra el siguiente error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'IdEmpleado' in 'where clause'")

`idEmpleado` es llave primaria de mi tabla. No logro encontrar la causa, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: hago todos los cambios normal pero, ejecuta error 1054 al final.

Comment: Básicamente no encuentra la columna IdEmpleado

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que es `IdEmpleado` (_i mayúscula_) y no `idEmpleado` (_i minúscula_)?

Comment: Tal como dice M.Gress el error es muy claro, por alguna razón no encuentra la columna `IdEmpleado` en la tabla. Lo primero a descartar es que la columna exista y que como comenta Marcos no estes cometiendo algún error tipográfico. Si en ese momento muestras las columnas de la tabla con `cursor.execute("SHOW columns FROM Empleados")` por ejemplo, ¿Que obtienes?

Comment: ¿Se puede saber que valor tiene la variable `idEmpleados` al momento de ejecutar la sentencia?.

Comment: si observas en la sentencia del error 1054 aparece 'idEmpleado'

Comment: bueno se ve como la i como si fuera mayuscula? no entiendo

Comment: El error lo muestra en mayuscula la i, pero el nombre de la columna es con minuscula y asi lo tengo en la sentencia sql, con minuscula!

Comment: te recomiendo que verifiques que el nombre del campo sea idéntico a la de tu tabla para descartar esa posibilidad.

Comment: Dices que el nombre de la columna es en minúscula pero en la consulta tienes: `where IdEmpleado...` no `where idEmpleado`...

Comment: Si estás seguro que existe ese campo, entonces, debes verificar que valor tiene la variable *idEmpleados* porque puede que tenga un valor no válido y el MySQL lo confunde con una columna.

Comment: ya lo cambie y sigue igual, where idEmpleado="+idEmpleados, !

Comment: ¿Puedes imprimir la variable sql para ver que estas mandando al servidor?

Comment: ok, ya solucione ese  inconveniente, debia ser where **idEmpleados**="+idEmpleados con **(s)**

Comment: ahora mi problema es con otra columna,!!!! 1054, "Unknown column 'salariobasico' in 'field list'". toca revisar entonces??

Comment: ok ya aprendi la leccion, de que los nombres  en la sentencia antes y despues del igual deben ser iguales ejm: idEmpleados**="+idEmpleados

Comment: por eso explotaba el error al final de la ejecucion..

Comment: nuevamente gracias FJSevilla.